# Dealing with PyArrow decimal128 precision

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, decimal, pyarrow

[some example data at the end]
I've just started working with PyArrow, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious here.

I have a project that I'm updating to (hopefully) better handle calculations on money. Mostly, these calculations are multiplying a normal money amount by a percentage, like `9.94 * 0.04`, things like that.

I had been using pandas v1.4.x and just had all the money as floats and was not consistent with rounding, which caused headaches. In the example above, I would want `9.94 * 0.04 = 0.40`, using normal rounding to two digits.

I was going to start forcing `decimal.Decimal` objects in everywhere instead of floats, when I saw that pyarrow has a builtin `decimal128` datatype that should work much better with pandas.

So, not I'm getting a lot of the following exception:

> pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Rescaling Decimal128 value would cause data loss

I'm also getting changes to precision that, while not raising exceptions, I don't think I want.

For example, I have a pandas dataframe with a column called 'Pay Rate' with a dtype of `pa.decimal128(12,2)`. When I do `df['Pay Rate'] * decimal.Decimal('0.04')`, the result is of type `pa.decimal128(15,4)`. I'm assuming it is merging together the precisions of the two things being multiplied in a way that is reasonable but that I don't want. (Note: If i just do `df['Pay Rate'] * 0.04`, the result is a `double[pyarrow]` type.)

I want the end of my transformations here to result in columns that are type `decimal128(12,2)`, and so I'm also then trying `df['my_col'] = df['my_col'].astype(pd.ArrowDtype(pa.decimal128(12,2))`, and that is then sometimes giving me the error above about data loss.

It makes sense to me that there is data loss because I am indeed telling it to just drop off some decimal points, but really what I want is it to round and then, yea, drop them.

Is there some switch of function to handle this that I'm missing?

### some example data

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
from decimal import Decimal

data = {'col1': {0: Decimal('39.60'), 1: Decimal('39.60'), 2: Decimal('21.60'), 3: Decimal('7.20'), 4: Decimal('18.00'), 5: Decimal('18.00'), 6: Decimal('72.00'), 7: Decimal('30.60'), 8: Decimal('36.00'), 9: Decimal('41.40')}, 'col2': {0: Decimal('0.98'), 1: Decimal('1.00'), 2: Decimal('0.97'), 3: Decimal('0.46'), 4: Decimal('0.52'), 5: Decimal('1.00'), 6: Decimal('1.00'), 7: Decimal('1.00'), 8: Decimal('1.00'), 9: Decimal('1.00')}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data,dtype=pd.ArrowDtype(pa.decimal128(12, 2)))
df['col3'] = df['col1'] * df['col2']
#df['col3'] has a dtype of decimal128(25,4)
df['col3'].astype(pd.ArrowDtype(pa.decimal128(12, 2)))
#raises exception
```

Comment: Why isn't ordinary rounding with floats good enough for this?  Rounding certainly is consistent, even if unexpected.  Another common way to handle this kind of thing is to store your values as integer pennies.

Comment: Hey, Tim. With round floats, I feel like I then am doing another round ever time i do an operation, which is annoying at least (but maybe that's what I'd end up doing trying to use decimal128). I'm also summing columns that have hundreds or thousands of rows (which isn't that many, I understand), and summing on the floats can cause variances. And then I am sometimes checking if a sum equals something else, and so with floats would need to check it approx. Regarding storing as pennies - I've seen that used, but it just feels ... inelegant... Using a decimal dtype seems like it should work here

Comment: If your fundamental unit is the penny, then I don't see how you can call it inelegant.  It certainly leaves you in complete control of arithmetic operations.  Only you know what you want to happen if you divide 1.00 by 3.

Comment: yea, calling it inelegant isn't right. i just don't like it and i don't know why, so trying to grasp at reasons why i shouldn't do it. it probably is right - will require refactor things to work for that, but no matter what i do there is going to be a lot of refactoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call round before casting:

```py
df['col3'].round(2).astype(pd.ArrowDtype(pa.decimal128(12, 2)))
```